# How to find a basis for subspace of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

I am doing this exercise:

> The cosine space $F_3$ contains all combinations $y(x) = A \cos x + B \cos 2x + C \cos 3x$. Find a basis for the subspace that has $y(0) = 0$.

I am unsure on how to proceed and how to understand functions as "vectors" of subspaces.

Comment: "vectors" are just things you can add to each other and multiply by numbers. You can do that with functions, so you can say that functions are vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many people have problems understanding functions (among other things) as vectors. I believe this is caused by the fact that when introducing vectors one most frequently uses elements of $K^n$ where $K$ is a field such as $\mathbb{R}$, which easily leads to the wrong intuition that a vector must look like something such as $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. But do not forget that a vector is simply an element of a vector space, and there are many examples besides $K^n$ for such spaces, you only need a field $K$, a set $V$ and two certain operations satisfying some basic properties.

For your case, I assume that the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$. $F_3$ is $3$-dimensional, with $\{\cos x,\cos 2x,\cos 3x\}$ being a basis: These functions span $F_3$ by definition, and they are linearly independent because if $A\cos x + B\cos 2x + C\cos 3x = 0$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then it must be $A=B=C=0$ (check!). By this you know that any subspace of $F_3$ is at most 3-dimensional.

Now we should show that the functions that satisfy $y(0)=0$ actually form a subspace $W$, but this is clear since such functions are obviously closed under addition and scalar multiplication, and the zero function is contained in this subspace.

The functions $\cos x - \cos 2x$ and $cos x - \cos 3x$ (which are elements of $F_3$) clearly satisfy $y(0)=0$ and they are linearly independent, since $$A(\cos x - \cos 2x) + B(cos x - \cos 3x) = (A+B)\cos x - A\cos 2x - B\cos 3x = 0$$
implies $A+B=-A=-B=0$ and hence $A=B=0$. Thus, these two functions lie in (i.e. are vectors of) $W$, so $W$ must be at least 2-dimensional.

Now if $W$ was 3-dimensional, it would be $W=F_3$, but note that the function $\cos x$ does not satisfy $y(0)=0$ and hence is no element of $W$.

Hence $\{\cos x - \cos 2x,  \cos x - \cos 3x\}$ is a basis of $W$.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question: how can I rigorously check that $A = B = C = 0$?

Comment: If $A\cos x + B\cos 2x + C\cos 3x = 0$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then it holds in particular for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$. For these values the resulting equations are $-B=0$ and $-A\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})+B\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})=0$. The first equation shows that $B=0$, and since $\cos(\frac{\pi}{6}) \neq 0$ the second equation shows that $A=0$. Hence it also must be $C=0$. So the idea is to take some specific $x\in\mathbb{R}$ so that the equation gets simplified.

Comment: Why do you select $cos x - cos 2x$ and $cos x - cos 3x$ as elements? Moreover, I don't get the passage where there is the implication $A+B = -A = -B = 0$

Comment: Selecting these two functions was just my choice. I saw that the whole space is $3$-dimensional, and then I tried to find some linearly independent elements of the subspace given by $y(0)=0$. If you know how the cosine function (and its stretched versions) look like, then these two elements are not very hard to find. I would suggest you to review the topic "linear independence" somewhere. Since $\cos x$, $\cos 2x$ and $\cos 3x$ are linearly independent, they can only trivially be linearly combined to zero, this is why $A+B=0$, $-A=0$ and $-B=0$.